# How to update a table taking values to a second sql instance?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two SQL Server instances on two virtual machines, `Test` server and `Production` server.

I need to do an `UPDATE` to the production server taking data values from test server.

For example :

```
UPDATE [server_production].dbname.mytable 
SET column1 = [server_test].dbname.mytable.column1
```

How do I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your production server, define a [Linked Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx) that points to your test server.

Then, on your production server you can run a query similar to the following to update your column:

```
UPDATE p
    SET column1 = t.column1
from <dbname>.<schema>.mytable p
join <TestLinkedServerName>.<dbname>.<schema>.mytable t
    on p.<id> = t.<id>
```

In the above query, you'll need to provide values for the placeholders:

- `<dbname>` - the name of the prod/test database
- `<schema>` - the schema in which the table is defined (typically *dbo*)
- `<TestLinkedServerName>` - the name you've given to the linked server
- `<id>` - your PK column, or a column that uniquely identifies rows and provides a way to join the two tables

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at redgate sql data compare

http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-compare/